# os/exec command fails even though the cmd string is working correctly in bash

Tags: bash, go, openssl

I'm trying to run a openssl command using os/exec but Run() returns an error.
In particular, launching my decryption command within go is not working but launching the same command (obtained with cmd.String()) with bash (or Powershell on Win) is fine.

I'm quite new to golang so maybe I'm missing something... this is my code:

```
if executable, ok := openssl[runtime.GOOS]; ok {
    cmd := exec.Command(executable, "enc", "-d", "-salt", "-aes-256-cbc", "-md", "sha256", "-pass", fmt.Sprintf(`pass:"%s"`, Password), "-in", inFilename, "-out", outFilename)
    fmt.Println(cmd.String())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Result: " + out.String())
} else {
    log.Fatal(errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("OS %s not supported", runtime.GOOS)))
}
```

EDIT:
this is the openssl error I get when running the command within Go:

> bad decrypt 140380576924992:error:06065064:digital envelope
> routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:610:

EDIT2: solved removing the double quotes around the password, thanks.

Comment: yeah, sorry. just edited my post.

Comment: **Don't use quotemarks `"` in the `-pass` value.** When you put e.g. `pass:"this that"` in a command to (any normal) shell, it actually passes `pass:this that` _without_ the quotes to the program being run, here openssl, which uses `this that` as the pw. You need to do the same. Including the quotes makes the password actually be `"this that"` which is wrong, which produces the wrong key, which decrypts wrong.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 you can put your comment as a reply so that this thread can appear as resolved.